# Accidently deleted (overridden) RAID1 filesystem

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, mount

I've created a RAID 1 with OpenMediaVault (OMV) and accidently "overriden" the /dev/md0 of the mounted RAID. I wanted to copy a file and placed the wrong command:

`cp openmediavault-aac95dea-f693-4e8c-af3d-f8331b2bc6bd.crt  /dev/md0`

The two disks and the created raid (/dev/md0) still exists, but the file system is no more.
I also can't mount it manually.

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1  5.5T  0 disk
└─md0          9:0    0  5.5T  0 raid1
sdb            8:16   1  5.5T  0 disk
└─md0          9:0    0  5.5T  0 raid1
mmcblk2      179:0    0 29.1G  0 disk
└─mmcblk2p1  179:1    0 28.8G  0 part  /
mmcblk2boot0 179:32   0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk2boot1 179:64   0    4M  1 disk
zram0        251:0    0   50M  0 disk  /var/log
zram1        251:1    0  1.9G  0 disk  [SWAP]
root@VAULT:~# mount /dev/md0
mount: /srv/dev-disk-by-id-md-name-vault-EXOS: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

If i want to (re)create the filesystem in the OMV-GUI it would wipe the whole drives.

Is there a possibility to recreate a filesystem from this RAID1 or should i plug one of the drives in my Windows PC, copy all the files and create it new?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: "should i plug one of the drives in my Windows PC, copy all the files and create it new?" That is the safest route.

Comment: That's assuming you can copy all the files... If you can't mount it on Linux, I doubt you'll be able to mount it on Windows (not to mention Windows won't understand mdraid).